# Change bearing based on rotateGestures in Google Maps for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using Google Maps SDK for iOS (version 2.1.1) with Xcode 8. I added a `UIView` and set its class to `GMSMapView` and linked up with an `IBOutlet` called `mapView`.

```
double bearing;
int zoomLevel;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    bearing = 30;
    zoomLevel = 20;

    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    if([CLLocationManager headingAvailable]) {
        _locationManager.headingFilter = 5;
        [_locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
    }

    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    mapView.settings.tiltGestures = NO;
    mapView.settings.scrollGestures = NO;

    // obtain my position
    CLLocation *myLocation = mapView.myLocation;

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:myLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                                            longitude:myLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                                                 zoom:zoomLevel
                                                              bearing:bearing
                                                         viewingAngle:45];
    mapView.camera = camera;
}
```

The View Controller uses 2 delegates : `CLLocationManagerDelegate` and `GMSMapViewDelegate`.

Updating map location is not a problem, but when I rotate the map, since the bearing value has not changed at all, once the location is updated, the bearing is reset and cancelled the rotation. How can I update the bearing after I rotate the map?

Here is the `didUpdateLocations:` delegate function:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations {
    CLLocation *myLocation = [locations lastObject];

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:myLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                                            longitude:myLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                                                 zoom:zoomLevel
                                                              bearing:bearing
                                                         viewingAngle:45];
    [mapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];
}
```

---

My idea is to rotate the map exactly like the mobile game PokemonGO.